# Taskkill.exe does not properly close WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf, taskkill

We use `taskkill.exe` in some of our automation test teardowns, some of which involve having to close a WPF application.

I've discovered that if more than one window is open, taskkill will kill the active window but not the entire application.  We would prefer not to have to use the /F flag because that does not allow the application to close cleanly and leaves our database "dirty".

Has anybody run into this problem and found a solution, or have any ideas before we take a radically different approach? The closest I could find is setting `Application.Current.ShutdownMode` to `OnMainWindowClose`, but of course that doesn't help if the main window is not the front window when `taskkill` is executed.

Comment: Maybe add a remoting endpoint in the application that listens for a shutdown command.

Comment: Taskkill doesn't kill windows, it kills processes.  It is an incredibly crude way to kill a process, given that you use "automation".  You'd only reach for that double-barreled shotgun when the automation didn't work.  Well, didn't get better.  Look in TaskMgr.exe and use View + Select Columns, tick Handles.  It it is not zero after you used the gun then you've got a driver problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the Process class could help you.

```
Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName("appname");
p[0].CloseMainWindow();
```

Comment: Our automation tests are run in Java, which (I assume) is why we're using an external command to close processes.  That's not to say we wouldn't consider some sort of Java variant of this that might work if it comes down to it.

Comment: Ahh.. sorry I had no idea your automation was Java based

Comment: Since it appears the answer to my problem may simply be "do it some other way", I'm going to mark this one as the answer.  Thanks for the suggestion.